# Linking to internal html pages with LinkLabel

Tags: vb.net, html, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink

Visual Basic:
Trying to get my VB program to run an internal HTML file without it needing to navigate back the the C: drive.

Using:

```
Private Sub frmMalphite_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LinkLabel1.Links.Add(6, 4, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\Test1\Test2.html")
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData.ToString())
End Sub
```

I can get the html page to run, however it would not work if I opened the project on another computer, because the absolute path given. Looking for a work around so I don't have to change the path on every computer I use to work on the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file exists on a drive on `MachineA`, then the only way you can open this from `MachineB` is to put the file on a [shared drive](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110612092923AA2xqoh) and access the file via this share.

This will work from any machine that has permissions to read that share.

Something like:

```
LinkLabel1.Links.Add(6, 4, "\\MachineA\SharedDrive\Test2.html")
```

You *may* have access to the hidden administrative share on MachineA (`\\MachineA\c$`) from MachineB but you can't rely on it.